# Show a subset of data based on a selection in a Shiny graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have the following Shiny Application (it is actually a bit more complicated but this one is better for reproduction purposes):

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(twitteR)

setwd("C:/Users/Marc/Dropbox/PROJECTEN/Lopend/bank_mining/test_data")
source("functions.R")

tweets <- data.frame(
  city = c("New york", "Texas"),
  tweet = c("Test1", "Test")
)


shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = "Tweetminer",
      titleWidth = 350
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      width = 350,
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Menu Item")
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
        tabBox(
          tabPanel("Set tweets2", 
          plotOutput('plot',
                     brush = brushOpts(
                       id = "plot1_brush"
                     )),
          h4("Brushed points"),
          verbatimTextOutput("brush_info")
        )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { 


    output$plot <- renderPlot({

      all_states <- map_data("state") 
      # Add more states to the lists if you want
      states_positive  <-c("new york")
      states_negative  <- c("texas")
      # Plot results
      ggplot(all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group)) +
        geom_polygon(fill="grey", colour = "white") +
        geom_polygon(fill="green", data = filter(all_states, region %in% states_positive)) +
        geom_polygon(fill="red", data = filter(all_states, region %in% states_negative))

      #brush = brushOpts(
      #  id = "plot1_brush"
      #)
    })

    output$brush_info <- renderPrint({
      brushedPoints(all_states, input$plot1_brush)
    })

  })
```

What I would like to include is the possibility to select a city and show a subset of the dataframe "tweets". So if I select New York it should show the relevant tweets of NY.

Right now I have the function:

```
output$brush_info <- renderPrint({
  brushedPoints(all_states, input$plot1_brush)
})
```

Which outputs the coordinates. But actually I want to create another step so tweets can be selected based on the coordinates I selected. Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: Have you looked at the `crosstalk` package?  This is the sort of thing it does.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what I think you're describing. You were pretty much there with the brushed points function. From there it was just a matter of extracting the brushed states and subsetting the tweets dataframe:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(twitteR)

setwd("C:/Users/Marc/Dropbox/PROJECTEN/Lopend/bank_mining/test_data")
source("functions.R")

tweets <- data.frame(
  city = c("new york", "texas"),
  tweet = c("Test1", "Test")
)


shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = "Tweetminer",
      titleWidth = 350
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      width = 350,
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Menu Item")
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
        tabBox(
          tabPanel("Set tweets2", 
                   plotOutput('plot',
                              brush = brushOpts(
                                id = "plot1_brush"
                              )),
                   h4("Brushed points"),
                   verbatimTextOutput("brush_info"),
                   h4("Selected States"),
                   verbatimTextOutput("select_states"),
                   h4("Selected States' Tweets"),
                   verbatimTextOutput("tweets")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { 


    output$plot <- renderPlot({

      all_states <- map_data("state") 
      # Add more states to the lists if you want
      states_positive  <-c("new york")
      states_negative  <- c("texas")
      # Plot results
      ggplot(all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group)) +
        geom_polygon(fill="grey", colour = "white") +
        geom_polygon(fill="green", data = filter(all_states, region %in% states_positive)) +
        geom_polygon(fill="red", data = filter(all_states, region %in% states_negative))

      #brush = brushOpts(
      #  id = "plot1_brush"
      #)
    })

    output$brush_info <- renderPrint({
      brushedPoints(all_states, input$plot1_brush)
    })

    output$brush_info <- renderPrint({
      brushedPoints(all_states, input$plot1_brush)
    })

    #get states from brushed coordinates
    brushed_states <- reactive({
      brushed <- brushedPoints(all_states, input$plot1_brush)
      unique(brushed$region)
    })

    #this is to show the selected states
    output$select_states <- renderText({
      brushed_states()
    })

    #subset the tweets dataframe by the states
    output$tweets <- renderPrint({
      tweets[(tweets$city %in% brushed_states()),]
    })


  })
```